# AWS Athena Partition Keys becomes as 'varchar'

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

For example, I have a two partition keys that are account_id as int and record_date as date. When I executed a query, Athena says these are varchar. I have to query with 'key'. Is it a usual case or I did something wrongly?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with DDL used to create this table?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a data crawler for partition repair and crawler configuration not set as don't change schema, crawler changes partition keys type as string.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).